# Одноклассники like из android-приложения

Tags: oauth, android

Для андроид-приложения необходимо реализовать like на стенку одноклассников. До этого не имел опыта с одноклассниками - я правильно понимаю, что эта возможность существует, но необходимо пройти [это](http://dev.odnoklassniki.ru/wiki/display/ok/Odnoklassniki.ru+Third+Party+Platform) ? Особенно пугает одобрение и "администрация проверяет приложение на работоспособность и соответствие требованиям сайта."

Само приложение одноклассников, как и в случае с остальными сетями, будет существовать только для обеспечения like вызовов - что же они собираются проверять ?

Или есть другое решение ?

Comment: >> Особенно пугает одобрение и "администрация проверяет приложение на работоспособность и соответствие требованиям сайта."

Лично меня пугает сам факт существования такой убогой, тормозной и глючной "соцсети".

Answer (score 1):

А кто Вас знает, может в фоне собираетесь лайкать все подряд. А как они будут проверять это - это их личное дело.

Правильным решением будет воспользоваться их API. Без этого будет заметно сложнее - придется эмулировать браузер, следить за изменениями интерфейса. И в любом случае, нужно будет как то получать параметры для авторизации. А большинство пользователей критически относиться к вводу своих паролей в левое приложение.

Comment: ну, как мне известно остальные подобным не занимаются(проверкой,регистрацией контактных данных итп). И какие у меня шансы вообще зарегистировать приложение, которое не имеет контента, а просто служит элементом контракта их АПИ ? "воспользоваться их API" - это, как я понимаю, после регистрации приложения ?

Comment: Если Ваше приложение делает что то полезное, то шансы высокие. Если же нет - то очень низкие. Если Вы можете объяснить в 10-15 слов за 10 секунд что приложение будет делать и почему это классно - разрешат.